# Read elements from a 4D numpy array using another array as index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a array `dataX` that is of shape (4, 9359, 10852) and I have the second array  `dataY` that is of shape (9359, 10852). `dataY` can have values from 1 to 6. I want to do the below.

1. Get location of 5.0s in `dataY`.
2. Use that as index in `dataX` and get values in all 4 dimensions as a smaller numpy array. And I have done this

---

```
idx = np.where(dataY == 5.0)    
element = dataX[:,idx[0],idx[1]]
```

`idx[0].size` = 860498

`element.shape` = (4, 860498)

But I want element to be a 3D array and not as 2D list. How do I do it?

Comment: Hi, you only have a 3D and a 2D array so this is confusing. Also, can you please format your code for more readability ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`idx` identifies those elements of `dataY` that are 5.0.  It found lots of those, but they can't (in general) be arranged in a 2d array.  So `dataY[idx]` will return a (860498,) array of 5's.

Similarly when `idx` is used to select items from `dataX`, it 'flattens' the last 2 dimensions.

This may be easier to visualize with small arrays that can be printed in full.

```
In [104]: y=np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
In [105]: y
Out[105]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
In [106]: idx = np.where(y%2)
In [107]: idx
Out[107]: (array([0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3]), array([1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2]))
In [108]: y[idx]
Out[108]: array([ 1,  3,  5,  7,  9, 11])
In [110]: np.ma.masked_array(y, y%2==0)
Out[110]: 
masked_array(
  data=[[--, 1, --],
        [3, --, 5],
        [--, 7, --],
        [9, --, 11]],
  mask=[[ True, False,  True],
        [False,  True, False],
        [ True, False,  True],
        [False,  True, False]],
  fill_value=999999)
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats very helpful to understand how it works